# How to reverse this bit operand?

Tags: java, binary, bit

Basically I have a number that is manipulated with bitwise operands as you can see here:

```
is[i_6_] = i_9_ - 256 | ~0x7fffffff;
```

I need to reverse/undo this bit operand..

```
| ~0x7fffffff
```

So that I would just have the value of:

```
i_9_ - 256r help!
```

How to reverse this bit operand?

Comment: Unless I'm misreading the "question", it can't be done. Imagine a single bit, and these cases: `0|1->1`, `1|1->1`, `0|0->0`, `1|0->1`. That is, we get: `x|1->1`, `0|0->0`, `1|1->1`. However, this is a problem because `1->x|1` means that we can either "go back" to `1->0|1` or `1->1|1` by a different `x`. Perhaps there is some missing context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this: And with the (~) inverse of the value

```
i_9_ - 256 & 0x7fffffff;
```

inverse of inverse ~(~)

Comment: you can also consider bitwise XOR (^) operator - havent tried it

Answer (score 3):

1st of all im assumming the expression you wrote is actually `(i_9_ - 256) | ~0x7fffffff`

```
| ~0x7fffffff
```

is effectively the same as

```
| 0x80000000
```

meaning it will make the highest bit of the original number (i_9_ - 256 according to what you said) into a "1" regardless of its original value.
so i dont think you can reverse this

Answer (score 2):

To just remove that bit would be, as you likely know:

```
& 0x7fffffff
```

But since you need to revert it to its previous state, you would need to--generally speaking--save the state of that most-significant bit prior to OR'ing to determine whether you should clear that bit or not.  The most direct way to obtain your result, then, would be to re-use the original value of i_9_, but without the OR operation this time:

```
= i_9_ - 256
```